# JS input onClick not defined

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

I'm starting a series of simple exercices in JS and im getting stucked just at the beiginning of this.

Can someone bring me some light about what is going on? I don't see where is the mistake.

Thanks :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Basicos Laura</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = ejerciciosBasicos;
    function ejerciciosBasicos() {
      //1) HACER UN MÉTODO QUE RECIBA UNA CADENA Y UN CARÁCTER Y DIGA SI ESE CARÁCTER PERTENECE A LA CADENA O NO.

      function comprobarCadena() {
        var palabra = document.getElementById("introducidoPorUsuario").value
        console.log = palabra;
        return palabra;
      } //cierra comprobarCadena
    } //cierra ejercicios basicos
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ejercicio1">
    Ejercicio 1
    <input type="text" id="introducidoPorUsuario">
    <input type="text" id="letraIntroducidaPorUsuario">
    <input type="button" value="Ok" onClick="comprobarCadena();">
    <input type="text" id="inResultado">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`comprobarCadena` isn't a global. It only exists in the scope of `ejerciciosBasicos`.

Don't use an `onclick` attribute. Bind your event handler with `addEventListener` inside `ejerciciosBasicos` so that it is in scope.

Comment: I've never used that (less than 1 month experience). I'm trying to undertand documentation on the mozzila developer but I cannot see how it works.

Comment: @KaiEis — Have you read the section headed "Add a simple listener"?